# How to unit test if the user is being redirected to login page if email not validated

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to write some unit tests for my code, I'm just learning how to write tests and I'm new to Laravel. Basically, I have a simple project, where the user should register and after validating their email, they are redirected to the landing page. In order to avoid some infinite redirects and bugs, I added a few lines of code that prevents the user to redirect himself to the landing page before verifying their email. So this is what I have in the controller file :

```
public function index(): View|RedirectResponse
    {
        if (auth()->user()->email_verified_at)
        {
            return view('landing.country', [
                'countries'  => Countries::all(),
            ]);
        }

        auth()->logout();
        return redirect(route('home'));
    }
```

So, If the user hasn't verified his email, if he attempts to view the blade only accessible to authenticated users, I'm logging him out and redirecting to the login page. Even though writing this was quite simple, I'm having a hard time coming up with a proper way to test this. How should I be able to approach testing this particular logout section? I have to test if the user attempts to enter auth only blade and check if he is being logged out and redirected to input page? Any help would be appreciated, currently I've been trying something like this in my test units :

```
public function test_if_user_is_logged_out()
    {
        User::factory()->create();
        $user = User::first();
        Auth::logout();
        $response = $this->actingAs($user)->get(route('landing.worldwide'));
        $response->assertRedirect(route('home'));
    }
```

But obviously it doesn't work. I'd be forever thankful for any suggestions and help!

Comment: Is there a reason you're wanting to log the user out instead of using the verification notice page (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/verification#the-email-verification-notice)?

Comment: Hey, I'm actually using that notice page as well, but I found some weird bugs that I'm fixing with that logout part. For example, if the verification email is sent and the user is transferred to that notice page, if he goes back and adds  the landing page's URL to the main URL, for example 'localhost/landing' like this, he can access that page still, which he shouldn't be able to do

Comment: Ah ok. Yeah, that doesn't sound like it should be possible at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update your test to something like:

```
public function test_an_unverified_user_is_logged_out_and_redirected()
{
    $user = User::factory()->unverified()->create();

    $this->actingAs($user)
        ->get(route('landing.worldwide'))
        ->assertRedirect(route('home'));

    $this->assertGuest();
}
```

`unverified()` is a method that is included with fresh installs of Laravel.
If you don't have `unverified()` in your `UserFactory`, you can simply change the user create call to be:

```
$user = User::factory()->create([
    'email_verified_at' => null,
]);
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for!! Appreciate the help

Comment: By the way, is there any chance you know some good documentation about testing email laravel's email verification? can't seem to find a lot about testing in google haha

Comment: @ceaiius What is it you're wanting to test exactly?

Comment: I have a few things to test, for example, I have to test verification.verify as well, also, have to test the custom notifications that I have made, like the ResetPasswordNotification and ValidateEmailNotificaiton and a few more things :D

Comment: @ceaiius Are you wanting to test they've sent, confirm the content is correct or something else?

Comment: I want to test If the they have confirmed the email and returned back to the page the url sends them to

Comment: @ceaiius Depending on how you're mailables are set up, you could simply pull out the URL (or build the url in your test and confirm it's in the email). Then, test that it updates the DB fields (or whatever it does) when you visit the link.